Assign a value based on range
I have a data set with values that correspond to time:
 value = "a", begin = 1.1, end = 1.67

I want to categorize the values based on a separate data set with values assigned to a range:
 1.1 - 1.8: "blue"

Thus a datapoint like "a" is assigned a category "blue".
I don't know where to start.
Thanks!
I cannot use range() because I am working with floats.
Otherwise, I am lost.

What if begin = 1.0 in this example? I.e., the value interval doesn't fit inside a category interval?

The data structure you are looking for is an interval tree.

It’s not possible to have a value outside the categories’ ranges. And i will definitely look at interval trees. Thanks!

You need to check if a value is within the end points of the range to assign it's label.  One way to do this is to create a list of the start, stop, label tuples that you want to assign.  Then create a function that takes a value, checks it against the list, and returns the label.
Since you have both a start and end in your data example, you might want to consider using a label for both of those values.
value = "a"
begin = 1.1
end = 1.67

labels = [
    (1.1, 1.8, 'blue'),
    (1.8, 2.2, 'green'),
    (2.2, 3.6, 'red'),
]

def get_label(value, label_list):
    for start, stop, label in label_list:
        if start <= value < stop:
            return label
    return 'NO-LABEL'

begin_label = get_label(begin, labels)
end_label = get_label(end, labels)


Thanks for your thoughts! What if there is a set of ranges - e.g. ‘a’, ‘b’ and ‘c’?
